# NestJS how to pass @Param and @Query in same request

Tags: parameters, nestjs, query-string, routeparams

I have this route set up:

```
  @Get('/name/like')
  findByLikeName(@Query() query: { supplierID: string; name: string }) {
    return this.supplierProductService.findByLikeName(query);
  }
```

Which utilises the query params in the underlying service:

```
  async findByLikeName({
    supplierID,
    name,
  }: {
    supplierID: string;
    name: string;
  }): Promise<SupplierProduct[]> {
    return await this.supplierProductRepository.findAll({
      where: {
        name: {
          [Op.like]: `%${name}%`,
        },
        supplierID: supplierID,
      },
    });
  }
```

However, let's say i want to move the supplierID into a /:supplierID route param, while maintaing the name (and potential other query params) in the query object, how would i go about implementing this?

Comment: just add `@Param('supplierID') supplierId: string` to `findByLikeName` parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've pretty much already got it. All you should need to do is set up the `@Get()` route to know it's using a URL parameter and do the following:

```js
  @Get('/name/like/:supplierID')
  findByLikeName(
    @Query() query: { name: string },
    @Param() param: { supplierID: string }
  ) {
    return this.supplierProductService.findByLikeName({...query, ...param});
  }
```